# The item \xxx\yyy.cs" was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter. Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is an mvc web application. I have read many blogs and articles which are relevant to this but does not find any solution.
i have checked in .csproj and does not find any duplicate entries for file in .csproj file.

Comment: What happens if you remove the offending file from your csproj file?

Comment: it gives same error for different file

Comment: If `YourPojectName.csproj.user` file exists, delete it and try to load.

Comment: it doesnt exist i checked

Comment: I would suggest posting your `.csproj` file. Most likely the problem lies within the file.

Answer (score 1):

Close Visual Studio.
Go to Folder where you saved project
Open projectname.csproj in notepade.
Find your file name under  tag
Remove if found duplicate entry and save project.

Open again project in Visual Studio and problem solved :)